# Kmeans clustering using jaccard distance matrix

Tags: r, twitter, cluster-analysis, k-means, tweets

I'm trying to create Jaccard distance matrix and perform K-means on it to give out cluster ids and the ids of elements in the cluster. The input for it is twitter tweets. The following is the code and i couldn't understand how to use initial seeds from a file for kmeans.

```
install.packages("rjson" ,dependencies=TRUE)
library("rjson")
install.packages("jsonlite" ,dependencies=TRUE)
library("jsonlite")

install.packages("stringdist" ,dependencies=TRUE)
library("stringdist")
data <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines(file("C:\\Users\\Yuzuru Onathoshi\\Desktop\\Assignment5_pxv142730_sxl162530\\Part2\\Input\\Tweets.json")),collapse=",")))

t.feature <- data
t.feature$geo<-NULL


Jmatrix<-stringdistmatrix(t.feature$text,t.feature$text,method = "jaccard")
colnames(Jmatrix) <- t.feature$from_user_id
rownames(Jmatrix) <- t.feature$from_user_id

fit <- kmeans(Jmatrix, 10)
```

[image: Jaccard Matrix]
[image: Tweets Matrix]

Comment: you can implement your own kmeans with jaccard distance, it should not be difficult.

Comment: @sandipan incorrect. k-means may not converge for other distances, unless you also replace the mean with an appropriate function.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse really? is there any theoretical result for that? what's the mathematical intuition behind it? also if not mean we can use k-medoid like function. Even though having the same optimization function as kmeans (with only the distance measure changed), intuitively I can't see why it won't converge. – sandipan 5 hours ago

Comment: Yes, PAM/k-medoids exists because the mean only optimizes least-squares... that is the mathematical intuition: the mean doesn't minimize arbitrary distance functions. It could make the cluster *worse* by distances.

Answer (score 1):

k-means does **not use a distance matrix**.

This is easy to see: it does not work on pairwise distances, but it only needs the deviation of a point from a *center* (which will usually not be a point of your data set).

It expects continuous numerical input data for clustering, and does *not* support arbitrary distance functions.

The core idea of k-means is *minimizing variance* (which is the same as minimizing squared Euclidean distances). Contrary to some tutorials and even textbooks, k-means does in fact *not* minimize distance (it minimizes *squared* distance, if your distance is Euclidean; but that may be a different minimum than the least-distance minimum). If you wanted k-means to minimize another distance, you have to find an appropriate "mean", i.e. a function that estimates the least-distance center point. Some generic substitutes have been proposed, e.g. PAM.

If you are outting a Jaccard distance matrix into k-means it will often yield a somewhat useable result, but it's not what you would expect. Rather than comparing points by Jaccard, but **you cluster them by squared Euclidean of their distance vectors**. It's easy to see that this values if 0 exactly if points have the same Jaccard distances to all others (including themselves), so in particular their Jaccard distance must be 0. But if your data set is unbalanced (there are some clusters with very many objects) then they will also have too much weight in this dual space.

If you need other distances (and can afford to compute a distance matrix) use hierarchical clustering (HAC) rather than k-means!

Comment: but I have to use Jaccard distance that's the problem and I have been given an initial set of centroids I don't know how to use them. the exact question I'm working on is the following link:http://www3.nd.edu/~dwang5/courses/spring15/assignments/A2/Assignment2_SocialSensing.html

Comment: the kmeans is giving right clustering for jaccard matrix too, i have a list of centers which should be used as centers to the kmeans but still have 25 as the cluster size .323906397735641088,
323906483584655360,
323906657333682176,
323907258301939713,
,......,

Comment: Notice the assignment says "Hint: Note that the tweets do not have the numerical coordinates in Euclidean space, you might want to **think of a sensible way to compute the "centroid" of a tweet cluster**." - so, what is your "sensible" way to get a cluster center?

Comment: How to calculate SSE on kmeans.

Comment: SSE, sum-of-squared-errors by definition is sum-of-squared-Euclidean-distances. Again, you'd need to replace this for Jaccard, just like the mean.