# Is there any package in R to use jaccard or cosine distance for k-medoid clustering?

Tags: r, similarity, euclidean-distance, cosine-similarity

I am using function `pam` in package `cluster` for partitioning around medoids.

```
pam(x, k, diss = inherits(x, "dist"), metric = "euclidean",
    medoids = NULL, stand = FALSE, cluster.only = FALSE,
    do.swap = TRUE,
    keep.diss = !diss && !cluster.only && n < 100,
    keep.data = !diss && !cluster.only,
    pamonce = FALSE, trace.lev = 0)
```

In the package for the metric distance, only `Euclidean` and `Manhattan` are provided. Is there any package which implements either `Jaccard` or `Cosine` (dis)similarity distance for k-medoid clustering?

I know that for Cosine od Jaccard similarity matrix, there are some packages such as `arules`, but how can I use those matrices as in input for clustering?

Comment: I don't think that there is a package called `pam`.  I think you must mean the function `pam` in the package `cluster`.  Take a look at This previous post  [kmeans-clustering-using-jaccard-distance-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858773/kmeans-clustering-using-jaccard-distance-matrix)

Comment: Thank you @G5W . I revised it. You are right. Nevertheless, I am doing k-medoids not k-means. That question is about k-means I think.